# react select - buffer onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would need to pause the onChange for the react-select component until the data is loaded into options. How could that be?

```
const handleSearch = () => {
 // call data to redux and add to function getOptions (THIS WORK OK - this doesn't interest me)
}

const handleSelect = () => {
 // need pause event while handleSearch is completed
 // **how to do this**
}

<Select
  ...
  isLoading={isSearching} 
  onInputchange={handleSearch}
  onChange={handleSelect}
  options={getOptions}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: One option is you can disable the select box until the data is available. Set `isDisabled ` as true until data is available.

Comment: I need to have the enter event captured and only after reading the data will confirm enter (without pressing enter again). You can type in the search box while waiting for data

Answer (score 0):

Create new state to detect whether handle search is completed or not.

```
const [isHandleSearchComplete, markHandleSearchAsComplete] = useState(false);

const handleSearch = () => {
    getOptions().then((res) => {
        // do something here
        markHandleSearchAsComplete(true)
    })
}

const handleSelect = () => {
    // if handle search is complete then stop the process
    if (isHandleSearchComplete) {
        return
    }

    // otherwise, do something
}
```

Comment: this function works, i need to treat the function `handleSelect`

Comment: @user3061527 I was confused by your question. I've updated my answer

Comment: I don't want to stop `handleSelect`, but pause, so pause execution of `handleSelect` until data is loaded and then automatically execute `handleSelect`